# Function - return every second word as CAPITALIZE

Tags: javascript

I want to change every other word in function to capitalize letters.
If only 1 word - then also capitalize.

Example:

```
asd asd asd asd -> asd ASD asd ASD
asd -> ASD
```

This is what I have:

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  let word = str.toUpperCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) return word;
}

console.log(capitalize("asd asd asd asd"));
```

Comment: asd asd asd asd -> asd ASD asd ASD

Comment: What exactly do you want `asd asd asd asd -> asd ASD asd ASD asd -> ASD`?

Comment: ex1 (asd asd asd asd -> asd ASD asd ASD)
ex2 (asd -> ASD)

Comment: I don't get the use case either. Do you want to capitalize each 2nd word where a 'word' is the function's string argument splitted/seperated by a whitespace and return it every second? For timings in js see e.g setInterval(function, milliseconds) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 5):

Using [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  return str
    .split(' ')
    .map((s, i, arr) => (arr.length == 1 || i % 2) ? s.toUpperCase() : s)
    .join(' ')
}

console.log(capitalize("asd asd asd asd"));
console.log(capitalize("asd"));
```

Using regex and [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

https://regex101.com/r/wdR9zt/1

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  return str.replace(/(\S+\s+)?(\S+\s*)/g, (m, p1 = '', p2) => p1 + p2.toUpperCase())
}

console.log(capitalize("asd asd asd asd"));
console.log(capitalize("asd"));
```

Comment: ok thx
I need to add now an "if" str is one word then return str s.toUpperCase

Comment: very efficient and short code, but I don't understand it at all :)

Comment: I guess, so I provided the links for documentation that contains better as well as an updated explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use split and then check to see if index number is even or odd

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  let words = str.split(" ");
  var result = "";
  
  if(words && words.length ==1)
      return words[0].toUpperCase();
  
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) 
    if(i % 2 != 0)
        result +=words[i].toUpperCase() + " ";
    else
        result +=words[i] + " ";
        
   return result;
}

console.log(capitalize("asd asd asd asd"));
console.log(capitalize("asd"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  const words = str.split(' ');
  if(words.length === 1) return str.toUpperCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(i % 2 !== 0) {
      const word = words[i];
      words[i] = word.toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  return words.join(' ');
}

console.log(`capitalize('abc')\n`, capitalize('abc'))
console.log(`capitalize('abc abc abc abc')\n`, capitalize('abc abc abc abc'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the String on spaces and capitalize every odd indexed word

```js
function capital(word){

let words=word.split(" ");

if(words.length==1){

return words[0].toUpperCase();

}

for(let i=1;i<words.length;i+=2){

words[i]=words[i].toUpperCase();
}

return words.join(" ");

}

console.log(capital("new new new new"));
```

Comment: Ok so if I understand correctly: 
1 - we split te word into a words 
2 - when lenght is equal 1, function will return UpperCase words
3 - else it will check the length of the words and if more then 1 then it will upperCase words[i] and join the words by " ".

Comment: yes , or if you want alternate uppercase word then just do index check

Answer (score 0):

Answer by User863 is just Perfect(Y) but here is how I did this

```
function toCap(){
let str = "asd asd asd asd";
const strArr = str.split(" ");
let newArr=[]
for (let [index, value] of strArr.entries())
{
if(strArr.length== 1){
return value.toUpperCase();
}
else if((index+1)%2 == 0){
newArr.push(value.toUpperCase());
}
else{
newArr.push(value);
}
}

return newArr.toString();
}
console.log(toCap())
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function capitalize(str) {
  let words = str.split(' ')
  if (words.length === 1) return words[0].toUpperCase()
  words.forEach((word, index) => {
    if (index % 2 !== 0) {
      words[index] = word.toUpperCase()
    }
  })
  return words.join(' ')
}

document.write(capitalize("asd"), '<br>');
document.write(capitalize("asd asd"), '<br>');
document.write(capitalize("asd asd asd asd"), '<br>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Array's reduce is a powerful function. Lets see a version using that:

```js
function capitalize(str) {
    const words = str.split(' ');
    const final = words.reduce((accumulated, currentWord, index) => {
        if (index % 2 === 0 || index === 0) {
            return accumulated + ' ' + currentWord.toUpperCase();
        } else {
            return accumulated + ' ' + currentWord;
        }
    }, '');
    return final;
}

console.log(capitalize('asd asd asd asd'));
console.log(capitalize('asd'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple loop:

```js
function capitalize (str) {
  const strArr = str.split(' ')
  const newArr = []

  for (let i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++) {
    const curr = strArr[i]

    if (strArr.length === 1) {
      newArr.push(curr.toUpperCase())
      continue
    }

    if (i % 2 === 0) {
      newArr.push(curr.toUpperCase())
      continue
    }

    newArr.push(curr)
  }

  return newArr.join(' ')
}

console.log(capitalize('asd asd')) // asd ASD
console.log(capitalize('asd')) // ASD
```